# How to avoid error on missing keys when using dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

How do I ignore missing keys in a `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` comprehension iteration?

@jezrael kindly answered my problem on making a df with dictionary values here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49072184/9242601

But I encountered a `Key Error: 'fees'` error because not all "Customers" have a 'fees' key, so rather than generating an error, I'd like the iteration to just move on to the next Customer and not record that customer in the df.

I still need a dataframe, so `try... except` and `if key in dict` won't work, because I will just end up with an empty (or non-existent) df.

Apologies for effectively spreading this question over two questions, but I didn't think it was worth repeating the complete initial question (hence the link).

Thanks.

Comment: `if key in dct`

Comment: or `{k: dict(v.get('fees')) for k, v in d.items()}` if you don't mind storing `None` as the value for items lacking the key.

Comment: or `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: {}.setdefault('fees', v.get('fees',[])) for k, v in d.items()}, orient='index')` - providing an empty default fees list if none is present - not sure if that fits into your data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a given key already exists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link's OK - it's in Stackoverflow and isn't going anywhere.

Meet the `dict.get` method. By way of a pre-amble, this is almost everything you need to know about it:

```
>>> d = {'present': 'real_value'}
>>> d.get('present')
'real_value'
>>> d.get('absent') is None
True
>>> d.get('absent', 'default')
'default'
```

You should find that the modified comprehension

```
{k: dict(v['fees']) for k, v in d.items() if v.get('fees') is not None}
```

serves your needs, but this is untested code. Possibly more readable is

```
{k: dict(v['fees']) for k, v in d.items() if 'fees' in v}
```

Comment: Thanks holdenweb. Solved my problem just fine

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways to solve this.

One way is to use a `try` `except` statement to catch the error.

Another way is to test is the key is in the dict `key in dict`.

Another would be to use the dict's get method `dict.get(key, default = None)` where the default option will return None if the value is not found or you can set it to want you need.

Comment: Good summarization of 3 ppls comments that were posted 4+ minutes befor your "answer" ...

Comment: I didn't see anyone mention the try except or the get method in the comments

Comment: Thats probably because creating a `try ... catch` around the `df2 = pd.DataFrame.fro...` statement leaves you with zero data - it will not create any Dataframe at all ...